# R ::tmap plot and display NA values in legend

Tags: r, legend, symbols, na, tmap

I want to map point data with results of bird counts. The point size should be scaled according to the number of birds that were counted. If an area has not been counted  an x should be displayed for NA values. How do I plot these data and reach a nice legend with the tmap package?

This is a similar example:

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE)) 
library(tmap)
data(World, metro) 

# put population size pop2020 to NA for some cities
metro$pop2020[10:300] <- NA 

# add column with code for the shape of the symbol (21 for data available, 4 for NA)
metro$shape_symbol <- 21 
metro[is.na(metro$pop2020), ]$shape_symbol <- 4

tm_shape(World) + tm_fill()+
  tm_shape(metro) + 
  tm_symbols(
    size = "pop2020",
    col = "black",
    shape = "shape_symbol", # use column shape_symbol in metro for the symbol 
  #  shapeNA = "4", # should plot NA as cross by default -  didn´t work for me 
    title.size = "subtitle", 
    legend.size.is.portrait=TRUE) +
tm_layout(legend.bg.color = "gray", 
          legend.frame = "black")
```

Which gives this output. Why are the NA values not shown? And how do I reach a nice legend output?

[image]

My aim is to reach this:

[image]

The name of the bird species should be given as bold legend title with an additional label "Anzahl" for the legend symbols below. Ideally the symbol x for NA should be place like this. I can paste(i) from a loop as legend title with title.size but how do I get a second title in the legend. 
Additional question: can I set the size of the points to a certain range? So that very small numbers have a minimum size in the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it myself using a workaround:

I added an extra layer and selected only the data with missing values. Then I added an additional legend element using tm_add_legend.

```
data(World, metro) 

# put population size pop2020 to NA for some cities
metro$pop2020[10:300] <- NA 

tm_shape(World) + tm_fill()+
  tm_shape(metro) + 
  tm_symbols(
    size = "pop2020",
    col = "black",
    title.size = "subtitle", 
    legend.size.is.portrait=TRUE) +
  tm_shape(metro[is.na(metro$pop2020),]) +
                 tm_dots(shape=4, size = 0.5, border.lwd = 0.5) +
  tm_layout(legend.bg.color = "gray", 
            legend.frame = "black") + 
    tm_add_legend(type="symbol", shape =4, labels = "not available", size = 0.5, border.lwd = 0.5, col = "black")
```